# Bing Search API for iOS

Tags: image, cocoa, api, size, bing

I'd like to use **Bing IMAGE API** in **PHP, JS or ObjC**, but classes and properties like
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250939.aspx
seem only available with C# or VB, is that right ?

I'd just like to get image search JSON result, **specifying width and height**...
Looks not possible from GET url :
api.bing.net/xml.aspx?Appid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&query=sushi&sources=image
I tried to insert **&size=small or &width=300** but doesn't send any change back.

I may use API with ObjC iOS and http://ibing.codeplex.com/ indeed implement WIDTH and HEIGHT properties but just as response information, not request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it :

1. Get a PHP Script to do the job on your server (this works for me for regular API Search, but should work for image search as well (perhaps, with some modifications...)) :

   ```
   function getOnePageUrls($querystr, $country="com", $page=1)
   {
       $markets = array(
           "com" => "en-US",
           "co.uk" => "en-GB",
           "ru" => "ru-RU",
           "de" => "de-DE",
           "fr" => "fr-FR",
           "es" => "es-ES"
       );

       $market = $markets[$country];

       if ($page==1) $offset = 0;
       else $offset = (($page-1)*50)+1;

       $appID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";  // your Bing App ID
       $searchstr = "http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=$appID&query=$querystr&sources=web&market=$market&web.count=50&web.offset=$offset";

       $json = file_get_contents($searchstr);

       $results = json_decode($json);
       $results = $results->SearchResponse->Web->Results;

       foreach ($results as $result)
       {
           $response[] = $result->DisplayUrl;
       }

       return $response;
   }
   ```
2. Get the response in your Objective-C code, using a simple GET
   request

And that's it! :-)

Comment: Merci docteur, your code use GET request with home made PHP, I was able to do that. My problem is that I wanna specify parameters when requesting (for instance image size), but classes provided by Bing API don t look usable in PHP, only C# or VB. 
So I can get photos whitouht problems, but I can t specify SIZE, BLACKWHITE, PORTRAITS, etc...

Comment: Just an idea : Would using C#.NET (ASP) code running on (an obviously Windows-based) server be an option?

Comment: So, it was just a matter of the right parameters, huh? Well done! :-)

Comment: Still, I can t call the API (using Bing classes) with PHP or ObjC

Comment: I want to integrate same api in my iOS application.Can u please tell me where i can register my app to get app id?